# A sufficient condition to ensure $\alpha=\beta$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be acute angles satisfying 
$$
\frac{\sin 2\alpha}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\sin2\beta}{\sin(2\beta+\alpha)}             
$$
Show then $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: Source? Motivation? Effort? Close.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Wait, wait, wait ... Now we summarily *close* no-effort questions? I thought the protocol was to prod the questioner into providing context.

Comment: A question in the elementary math. But I can not solve it...

Comment: @Blue, I choose to prod the questioner into providing context by raising the possibility of closure.

Comment: xldd, please; where did you come across the question? Why does it interest you? What do you know about trigonometry, and about trigonometric identities? Have you ever seen anything about $\sin(x+y)$, and do you see how it might apply to this problem? Math is for doing, not watching, and if you try something and it doesn't work, no one dies, you just try something else. You must know something about this problem --- please share it with us. Or else we'll shut it down.

Comment: This problem is about trigometry, a question arised by my little mate. However, I become a PhD, not familiar to that now.

Comment: Mathematics Ph.D. ?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for this problem. Here we have to use the following identities
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin A\sin B&=&-\frac{1}{2}[\cos(A+B)-\cos(A-B)],\\
\cos A-\cos B&=&-2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2},\\
\sin 3A&=&3\sin A-4\sin^3 A,\\
\sin 5A&=&16\sin^5 A-20\sin^3 A+5\sin A.
\end{eqnarray*}
We obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\frac{\sin 2\alpha}{\sin(2\alpha+\beta)}=\frac{\sin 2\beta}{\sin(2\beta+\alpha)}\\
&\Leftrightarrow&\sin 2\alpha\sin(2\beta+\alpha)=\sin 2\beta\sin(2\alpha+\beta) \\
&\Leftrightarrow&-\frac{1}{2}[\cos(3\alpha+2\beta)-\cos(\alpha-2\beta)]=-\frac{1}{2}[\cos(3\beta+2\alpha)-\cos(\beta-2\alpha)]\\
&\Leftrightarrow&\cos(3\alpha+2\beta)-\cos(3\beta+2\alpha)=\cos(\alpha-2\beta)-\cos(\beta-2\alpha)\\
&\Leftrightarrow&-2\sin\frac{5(\alpha+\beta)}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}=-2\sin\frac{3(\alpha+\beta)}{2}\sin\frac{-\alpha-\beta}{2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow&\sin\frac{5(\alpha+\beta)}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}=-\sin\frac{3(\alpha-\beta)}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow&\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\left[16\sin^5 \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-20\sin^3 \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+5\sin \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right]\\
&&=-\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\left[3-4\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right]\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus we have

Case 1: $\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}=0$. Since $\alpha,\beta$ are acute angles, so $\alpha=\beta$.

Case 2: $16\sin^5 \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-20\sin^3 \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+5\sin \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}=-\left[3-4\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right]\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$. Since $\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\neq 0$, we obtain
$$ 4\sin^4 \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-5\sin^2 \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+2=\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}.$$
Letting $x=\sin^2\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$, we have
$$ 4x^2-5x+1=-1+\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$$
or
$$ (1-x)(1-4x)=-1+\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}. $$
Note $x\in[0,1]$. If $\frac{1}{4}\le x\le 1$, then $1-4x\le 0$ and hence
$$ (1-x)(1-4x)=-(1-x)(4x-1)=-\frac{1}{4}(4-4x)(4x-1)\ge -\frac{1}{4}\frac{9}{4}=-\frac{9}{16} $$
from which, we have $-1+\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\ge -\frac{9}{16}$ or $\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\ge \frac{7}{16}>0$. This implies $\alpha\neq \beta$.

If $0\le x<\frac{1}{4}$, we have $(1-x)(1-4x)> 0$ and $-1+\sin^2\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\le 0$ and hence this will never occur.

Thus only Case 1 holds or $\alpha=\beta$.